# Interacting with Amazon Elasticsearch Service using JAVA SDK

Tags: amazon-elasticsearch

I am having trouble finding examples of how to interact with an amazon elasticsearch cluster using the amazon sdk. Can someone point me to examples? I've found javadocs for things like AWSCredentials and the AWSElasticsearchClient, just looking for concrete examples of how to glue everything together. I'm looking for how to do things like:

-create an index

-index documents

-delete documents

Just the basic operations. I assume that there is an 'amazon' way of creating a client and interacting with the cluster since they provide an sdk and a credentials object for signing requests.

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples

Answer (score 2):

Did a little more digging and I guess those SDK classes are more for doing 'infrastructure' type operations against your elasticsearch instance, like spinning up a new node, etc, not for creating a client to do search/index type operations. I guess I can just use a Jest Client instead.

Comment: Were you able to successfully implement this using Jest Client?